# PHP Curl Twitter Verificar se dados estão corretos

Tags: php, libcurl, twitter-api

Consegui fazer o que eu queria, porém como faço a verificação pra ver se os dados do usuário esta correto?

Na pergunta anterior eu perguntei como faria pra obter todos os cookies caso realmente o usuário e senha exista no Twitter, eu consegui fazer isto com o código que vou colocar aqui.

Mas como eu verifico se os dados estão corretos?

Se tiver mostra a mensagem: **Login e senha corretos**, caso contrário mostrar-me **Login e senha incorretos**.

Meu código:

```
<?php

$username = 'pdosilva1020';
$password = '';

function start($username, $password) {
    $request = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($request, [
            CURLOPT_URL                         => 'https://twitter.com',
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST       => 'GET',
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => false,
            CURLOPT_HEADER                  => true,
            CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR               => getcwd() . '/cookies/' . $username . '.txt',
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT               => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
            CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION  => function($curl, $header) use (&$cookie) {
                if (stripos($header, 'Set-Cookie:') === 0) {
                    if (preg_match('/^Set-Cookie: \s*([^;]*)/i', $header, $matches)) {
                        $cookie .= $matches[1] . '; ';
                    }
                }
                return strlen($header);
            }
        ]
    );
    $response = curl_exec($request);

    preg_match('/value="(.*?)" name="authenticity_token"/', $response, $matches);

    $authenticity_token = $matches[1];

    $post_fields = http_build_query([
        'session' => [
            'username_or_email' => $username,
            'password'                  => $password
        ],
            'return_to_ssl'                 => true,
            'scribe_log'                        => '',
            'redirect_after_login'  => '/',
            'authenticity_token'        => $authenticity_token
        ]
    );

    curl_setopt_array($request, [
            CURLOPT_URL                         => 'https://twitter.com/sessions',
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST       => 'POST',
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS          => $post_fields,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => false,
            CURLOPT_HEADER                  => true,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => true,
            CURLOPT_COOKIE                  => $cookie,
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT               => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER          => [
                'accept-language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
                'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'origin: https://twitter.com',
                'referer: https://twitter.com/login',
            ],
        ]
    );

    $response = curl_exec($request);
    curl_close($request);

}

var_dump(start($username, $password));
```

Comment: Você deixou seu usuário e senha exposto no código e ainda publicou aqui.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que para responder isso basta que você erre e acerte sua senha no Twitter e veja a diferença das respostas.

Me baseando nisto, a diferença entre a senha certa e errada é que:

- Se **acertar** ele da um "Location:" para:

  https://twitter.com/
- Se **errar** ele da um "Location:" para:

  https://twitter.com/login/error?username_or_email=nome&redirect_after_login=%2F

Se você sabe como o que o `CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION` funciona, então sabe como obter o "Location" através dele.

---

Recomendo que [leia a documentação](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION.html), ao invés de dar Ctrl+C, Ctrl+V sem nem fazer ideia do que o seu código está fazendo. O seu código já usa o recurso que poderia ser utilizado para este proposito.

Como um exemplo, você poderia utilizar:

```
    CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION  => function($curl, $header) use (&$cookie, &$location) {
        if (stripos($header, 'Set-Cookie:') === 0) {
            if (preg_match('/^Set-Cookie: \s*([^;]*)/i', $header, $matches)) {
                $cookie .= $matches[1] . '; ';
            }
        }

        if (stripos($header, 'Location:') === 0) {
            $location = trim(str_ireplace('Location:', '', trim($header)));
        }

        return strlen($header);
    }
```

Agora você tem o `$location`, ele deve ser definido anteriormente como `$location = ''`. Isto deve ser feito na sua segunda requisição, obviamente, pois é ele quem faz o login.

Assim você poderá fazer:

```
$location = trim(explode('?', $location)[0], '/');

switch ($location) {
    case 'https://twitter.com':
        echo 'Tudo certo';
        break;
    case 'https://twitter.com/account/access':
        echo 'Conta bloqueada';
        break;
    case 'https://twitter.com/account/login_verification':
        echo 'Conta exige 2FA';
        break;
    default:
        echo 'Senha inválida';
        break;
}
```

Isso é uma das milhões de possibilidades que você tem. Lógico que você deve desligar o `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`, ou ele vai seguir o caminho e retornará uma valor diferente.

---

No final ficará como:

```
function start($username, $password)
{
    $request = curl_init();
    $cookie = '';
    $location = '';

    curl_setopt_array($request, [
            CURLOPT_URL => 'https://twitter.com',
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
            CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
            CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => getcwd() . '/cookies/' . $username . '.txt',
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
            CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION => function ($curl, $header) use (&$cookie) {
                if (stripos($header, 'Set-Cookie:') === 0) {
                    if (preg_match('/^Set-Cookie: \s*([^;]*)/i', $header, $matches)) {
                        $cookie .= $matches[1] . '; ';
                    }
                }
                return strlen($header);
            }
        ]
    );
    $response = curl_exec($request);

    preg_match('/value="(.*?)" name="authenticity_token"/', $response, $matches);

    $authenticity_token = $matches[1];

    $post_fields = http_build_query([
            'session' => [
                'username_or_email' => $username,
                'password' => $password
            ],
            'return_to_ssl' => true,
            'scribe_log' => '',
            'redirect_after_login' => '/',
            'authenticity_token' => $authenticity_token
        ]
    );

    curl_setopt_array($request, [
            CURLOPT_URL => 'https://twitter.com/sessions',
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $post_fields,
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,
            CURLOPT_COOKIE => $cookie,
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
            CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION => function ($curl, $header) use (&$cookie, &$location) {
                if (stripos($header, 'Set-Cookie:') === 0) {
                    if (preg_match('/^Set-Cookie: \s*([^;]*)/i', $header, $matches)) {
                        $cookie .= $matches[1] . '; ';
                    }
                }

                if (stripos($header, 'Location:') === 0) {
                    $location = trim(str_ireplace('location: ', '', trim($header)));
                }

                return strlen($header);
            },

            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
                'accept-language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
                'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'origin: https://twitter.com',
                'referer: https://twitter.com/login',
            ],
        ]
    );

    $response = curl_exec($request);
    curl_close($request);


    echo '<br>';
    echo $location = trim(explode('?', $location)[0], '/');

    switch ($location) {
        case 'https://twitter.com':
            echo 'Tudo certo';
            break;
        case 'https://twitter.com/account/access':
            echo 'Conta bloqueada';
            break;
        case 'https://twitter.com/account/login_verification':
            echo 'Conta exige 2FA';
            break;
        default:
            echo 'Senha inválida';
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Inkeliz, eu usei `CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION` no primeiro `request`, pra pegar os cookies não faço a minima ideia, teria um exemplo?

Comment: Usando `curlinfo_header_size` e o `DOMDocument` eu vi esses links porém não consegui.

Comment: @Inkeliz ele pode fazer desta forma porém o twitter requer a utilização do `CURLOPT_COOKIE` Desta forma não dá pra formatar os cookies no httpheaderfunction correto ?

Comment: O `CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION` permite que você obtenha qualquer informação do cabeçalho. Os cookies são apenas é apenas um cabeçalho qualquer. O `CURLOPT_COOKIE` espera qualquer valor no formato `Nome=Valor;`. Então, qualquer coisa, inclusive o `HEADERFUNCTION` é capaz de resultar nesse formato.

Comment: Ta, o @Coruja, foi na pergunta que eu queria fazer, porém quais outros métodos `HEADERFUNCTION` surporta? quero fazer várias verificações uma delas é se a conta está bloqueada. @Inkeliz

Comment: @LoucãoDEV, [leia a documentação](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION.html)... O `HEADERFUNCTION` permite obter qualquer header, qualquer cabeçalho enviado. O `Location` é apenas um deles e que obviamente você conseguirá obter.

Comment: @Inkeliz, marquei como resolvido, porém, apenas, login e senha corretos ou incorretos funcionam, o de conta bloqueada e de verificação não funcionam como proceder?

Comment: Não tenho como testar todas as possibilidades, apenas testei: senha inválida, senha correta e o uso de 2FA. O link de conta bloqueada foi o que você mesmo informou numa outra questão. Editei o post e acrescentei exatamente a função que utilizei para testes.

Comment: 2FA seria o que? Eu tipo to tentando usar `account/access` pra mostrar a mensagem mas tá dificil @Inkeliz, teria como me ajudar nisso?

Comment: Não funciona, o resto dos links apenas o case: 'https://twitter.com' e o default, o resto não funciona. se eu dou um var_dump em $header msm com os dados incorretos me retorna twitter.com e mais nada no location:

Comment: @Guilherme, é porque o fluxo de redirecionamento não é como está perguntado e não tenho contas para testar. Pleo que me lembro, ele redireciona para o `twitter.com` e de lá ele vai para o outro (o `/access`). Talvez você possa habilitar o "FOLLOW_LOCATION" e pegar o url ativo (CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL). Dai você iria pagar a última página. ;)

Comment: @Inkeliz Eu tenho varias contas pra testar ja ativei o follow location e nada

Answer (score 1):

A solução mais **simples** que eu achei foi a seguinte, no `curl` que recebe meu `post`:

```
curl_setopt_array($request, [
        CURLOPT_URL                         => 'https://twitter.com/sessions',
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST       => 'POST',
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS          => $post_fields,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => false,
        CURLOPT_HEADER                  => true,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => true,
        // CURLOPT_COOKIE                   => $cookiesOBJ->cookies,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT               => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER          => [
            'accept-language: pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4',
            'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'origin: https://twitter.com',
            'referer: https://twitter.com/login',
        ],
    ]
);

$response = curl_exec($request);
curl_close($request);
```

Eu deixei `CURLOPT_HEADER => false` estava como `true`, e logo depois retornei em `json`:

```
if ($response === '') {
    echo json_encode([
            'error'     => false,
            'message'   => 'Logado com sucesso, aguarde...'
        ]
    );
} else {
    echo json_encode([
            'error'     => true,
            'message'   => 'Usuário e/ou Senha incorretos'
        ]
    );
}
```

Deixando o `CURLOPT_HEADER` como `false` me retorna um corpo de erros, se caso estiver dados errados, se estiver certo me retorna uma `string` vazia, `string = ''`,