# CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION - Retorno de cookies

Tags: php, libcurl, http-headers

Tenho esta função que retorna `Cookies` de um determinado site, estou aprendendo `HTTP HEADERS`,

Mas eu não sei o porque deste aviso se estou retornando meus cookies tudo **ok**,
O que tem de errado no meu código?

> Notice: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int in
>   C:\wamp64\www\tr\api\login.php on line 34

Aqui está meu código:

```
<?php

function cookies() {
    $request = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($request, [
            CURLOPT_URL                         => 'https://tr.com',
            CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST       => 'GET',
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => false,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
            CURLOPT_HEADER                  => true,
            CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION  => function($curl, $header) use (&$cookie) {
                if (stripos($header, 'Set-Cookie:') === 0) {
                    $cookieOBJ = new \stdClass();
                    $cookieOBJ->cookies = '';
                    if (preg_match_all('/^Set-Cookie: \s*([^;]*)/i', $header, $matches)) {
                        foreach ($matches[1] as $cookie) {
                            $cookie = explode('=', $cookie);

                            $key = (!empty($cookie[0])) ? $cookie[0] : '';
                            $val = (!empty($cookie[1])) ? $cookie[1] : '';

                            $cookieOBJ->{"$key"} = $val;

                            $cookieOBJ->cookies .= $key . '=' . $cookieOBJ->{"$key"} . '; ';
                        }
                    }
                    return $cookieOBJ;
                }
                return strlen($header);
            }
        ]
    );
    $response = curl_exec($request);
    curl_close($request);
}

var_dump(cookies());
```

Obs: Preciso que me retorne da seguinte forma:

```
C:\wamp64\www\tr\api\login.php:28:
object(stdClass)[2]
  public 'cookies' => string 'fm=; ' (length=5)
  public 'fm' => string '' (length=0)
```

E ao utilizar a minha variável `$cookieOBJ` me retorna todos ou `$cookieOBJ->cookies`, porém se eu utilizar `$cookieOBJ->fm` me retorna um erro:

> Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$fm in
>   C:\wamp64\www\tr\api\login.php on line 28

Qual a solução?

Answer (score 1):

Esse código não vai funcionar nunca, primeiro veja a documentação do [`CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION.html):

> This callback function must return the number of bytes actually taken care of. If that amount differs from the amount passed in to your function, it'll signal an error to the library. This will cause the transfer to get aborted and the libcurl function in progress will return CURLE_WRITE_ERROR.

O seu `return $cookieOBJ;` não faz o minimo sentido. Assim como também não faz sentido fazer um `foreach` nem `preg_match_all`, se cada vez só terá um cookie, não vários. Afinal, pelo [`CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION.html):

> The header callback will be called once for each header and only complete header lines are passed on to the callback.

Se for ver a [RFC6265](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265.txt):

> Origin servers SHOULD NOT fold multiple Set-Cookie header fields into a single header field. The usual mechanism for folding HTTP headers fields (i.e., as defined in [RFC2616]) might change the semantics of the Set-Cookie header field because the %x2C (",") character is used by Set-Cookie in a way that conflicts with such folding.

Logo, cada cabeçalho do `Set-Cookie`, enviado pelo servidor, terá apenas um único cookie.

---

Uma maneira muito mais fácil, que [inclusive você já usou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/243421/15089), inclusive [deve ter surgido daqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/215803/15089) e [foi explicado aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/217275/15089):

```
CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION => function($curl, $cabeçalho) use (&$cookie){

    if(stripos($cabeçalho, 'Set-Cookie:') === 0){
        if(preg_match('/Set-Cookie:\s?(.*?);/i', $cabeçalho, $matches)) {
            $cookie .= $matches[1] . '; ';
        }
    }

    return strlen($cabeçalho);
}
```

Isso irá criar uma string, contendo `Nome=Valor;`, mas se realmente deseja um objeto, basta alterar o REGEX e criar o objeto FORA da função.

A ideia é passar a variável como referencia em `&$cookie` que vai permitir obter o resultado, ou seja:

```
function cookies()
{
    $request = curl_init();
    $cookie = new \stdClass();  // Inicia aqui fora

    curl_setopt_array($request, [
            CURLOPT_URL => 'SEU.SITE.COM',
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_NOBODY => true, // Você só precisa o header, não do corpo
            CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS => CURLPROTO_HTTPS, // Você só usa HTTPS, não STMP, por exemplo.
            CURLOPT_SSLVERSION => CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2, // A versão mais segura de TLS.
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2, // Usar false é claramente inseguro.
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 1, // Usar false é claramente inseguro.
            CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION => function ($curl, $header) use (&$cookie) {
            // Estamos usando o `&$cookie` ou seja uma "referencia" a variável lá de fora.
                if (stripos($header, 'Set-Cookie:') === 0) {
                    if (preg_match('/^Set-Cookie: \s*([^=]*)=([^;]*)/i', $header, $matches)) {
                        $cookie->{$matches[1]} = $matches[2];
                    }
                }
                return strlen($header);
            }
        ]
    );

    $response = curl_exec($request);
    curl_close($request);

    return $cookie; // Retornamos aqui.
}
```

O REGEX `/^Set-Cookie: \s*([^=]*)=([^;]*)/i` fará o trabalho de pegar o nome e valor do cookie, isot será adicionado usando:

```
$cookie->{$matches[1]} = $matches[2];
```

O `$cookie` é uma referencia (devido ao uso do `(&$cookie)`) ao `$cookie = new \stdClass();` iniciado nas primeiras linhas. Algumas outras mudanças foram feitas por segurança, se isso não for importante, o que é comum em PHP, basta remove-las.

Comment: Ta tudo certo, mas eu queria, que retorna-se por exemplo: `fm=0;` e está me retornando assim: `public 'fm' => string '0' (length=1)`

Comment: Ué, está retornando justamente o que você diz querer na sua postagem "Obs: Preciso que me retorne da seguinte forma:". Se você quer acessar cada valor basta fazer `$seuscookies = cookie();` e então `$seuscookies->fm`. Se quiser formatar todos os cookies, para ficar tudo junto, utilize `http_build_query($seuscookies, '', '; ', PHP_QUERY_RFC3986) . ';';`, assim ficará tudo da maneira "que agora você quer".

Comment: Funcionou. Obrigado.